# how get BackHandler event while keyboard is open in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am working on a chat app, in which I want that, when user click on android default back button it should close the keyboard and also Goback in navigation.

I know I can capture the keyboard close event but I am using that event for opening the emoji picker, so I can not use keyboard dissmiss event

and the main issue is when keyboard is open and Back button pressed it only closes the keyboard and does not fire event in BackHandler. if keyboard is close then it works fine..

```
const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction,
    );
```

Comment: Hello:)
A quick way to do it is to close the keyboard then reopen it.

Comment: @AdamBasha I have already tried this way but it wont work because this event is using in emoji picker events

Answer (score 0):

- The issue you're facing is because the hardware back button event is not being triggered when the keyboard is open. This is because the hardware back button event is only triggered when the navigation stack is not empty. When the keyboard is open, it consumes the back button event and doesn't propagate it to the navigation stack.
- To resolve this issue, you can use the keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide events. These events provide information about the keyboard's size and animation duration, which you can use to determine if the keyboard is an emoji keyboard or not.

  ```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
  import { BackHandler, Keyboard } from 'react-native';

  const App = () => {
   const [keyboardOpen, setKeyboardOpen] = React.useState(false);

   const backAction = () => {
    if (keyboardOpen) {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
   };

   const keyboardDidShow = (event) => {
    setKeyboardOpen(true);
   };

   const keyboardDidHide = (event) => {
    setKeyboardOpen(false);
   };

   const keyboardWillShow = (event) => {
    if (event.endCoordinates.height > 300) {
      setKeyboardOpen(true);
    }
   };

   const keyboardWillHide = (event) => {
    setKeyboardOpen(false);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', keyboardDidHide);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', keyboardWillShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', keyboardWillHide);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
      Keyboard.removeAllListeners('keyboardDidShow', keyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeAllListeners('keyboardDidHide', keyboardDidHide);
      Keyboard.removeAllListeners('keyboardWillShow', keyboardWillShow);
      Keyboard.removeAllListeners('keyboardWillHide', keyboardWillHide);
    };
   }, []);

   // Your component code here
  };
  ```

Comment: I appreciate you effort, but there is a issue in your statement, in point #2: you said "in your backAction function, you can check if the keyboard is open." but in point #1 you said "When the keyboard is open, it consumes the back button event", which means it will never fire when keyboard is open..

Comment: You are correct that the hardware back button event is not triggered when the keyboard is open. However, the Keyboard.addListener event is triggered when the keyboard is opened or closed. This allows us to set a flag to indicate whether the keyboard is open or not.

In the backAction function, we check if the keyboard is open. If it is, we close the keyboard using Keyboard.dismiss() and then return true to indicate that we have handled the back button event. This prevents the default back button behavior from occurring.

Comment: If the keyboard is not open, we return false to indicate that we have not handled the back button event. This allows the default back button behavior to occur, which is to go back in the navigation stack.

Comment: hmm,you are right but we have a problem here, that we are using keyboard close event to ope the emoji keyboard, so we con not distinguish the keyboard close event that how it get close by back button or by emoji keiboard.

Comment: @iLS nn  Check out my modified code now.